# Gmail putting the email under promotions tab

Tags: c#, email, mandrill

I have a very simple email that gmail is putting under promotions tab. This emails goes out to the client when their registration gets approved. So the email has

```
From email and name: belongs to the SalesRep for the area

Subject line: Company - Registration Approved

Header image

Content starts with "Dear First Name".
```

It ends with a proper from signature with a name of the SalesRep for their area.

The actual content is single paragraph with a link to the site. It is two lines at 560px width.

Footer has the site url and then company name with address.

What can I do different here so that email email goes to the primary tab?

We are using Mandrill. The template is defined in Mandrill and we use the API to pass the dictionary items to the template and then fire the email. Its a .net C# code.

Comment: If you are sending the email with PHP, check if you have `headers` defined for the send mail. Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), example 2

Comment: We are using Mandrill. The template is defined in Mandrill and we use the API to pass the dictionary items and to the template and then fire the email. Its a .net C# code.

Comment: Add it to your question, there are to many good answers.